# Static member initialization in python from static member value of a derived class

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite, oop, orm

Is it possible to initialize a static member of a base class from a static member of a derived class in python (2.7)?

Namely, suppose I have a bunch of classes that map the entities stored in a simple database:

```
class EntityA(EntityBase):
    entityName = 'EntA' # the name of the entity in the DB
    ...

class EntityB(EntityBase):
    entityName = 'EntB' # the name of the entity in the DB
    ...
```

and suppose that the DB is built following the rule that all entities have an id field that is named 'id_*name-of-the-entity*'. So, 'id_EntA' and 'id_EntB' are the names of the id fields in the DB for EntityA and EntityB respectively.

Now I'd like to generate these two names from the (abstract) base-class (EntityBase) only once, but I can't find a way to do it...

I'd like to write something like:

```
class EntityBase:
    idFieldName = 'id_' + *derived-class*.entityName
    ...
```

I know I could write a simple function that returns the concatenated string, but I'd like it not to be evaluated every time I call that function. That should be possible, since all the information needed to build the `idFieldName` value are stored in static variables.

Comment: But `idFieldName` is a *static* member **of `entityBase`**...

Comment: If you want to hook into class creation, look into metaclasses.

Comment: @Willem: yes, I'd only like it to be generated once (at "compile time") from the value of a static member of the derived class... does it make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can use is a [**metaclass**](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Metaclasses). A metaclass is the class to which a certain class belongs.

Then you can use:

```
class MetaEntityBase(type):
    def __new__(meta, name, bases, dct):
        if 'entityName' in dct:
            dct['idFieldName'] = 'id_'+dct['entityName']
        return super(MetaEntityBase,meta).__new__(meta,name,bases,dct)
```

Then you can write:

```
class EntityBase:
    __metaclass__ = MetaEntityBase
```

and now if we query for `EntityA.idFieldName`, we get:

```
>>> EntityA.idFieldName
'id_EntA'
```

Here we used an `if` statement to inspect the `dct` first. The **`dct` is a dictionary that contains the classes members *before* initialization**: so it contains all methods, class fields, etc.

We thus check if `'entityName'` is one of the keys (this thus means that at the class level, it is defined somewhere). If that is the case, we add a new element to the `dct`: `'idFieldName'` that prepends the `entityName` with `id_`. Of course you can define an `else` case for what to do if there is no such attribute `entityName`

The `__new__` of a metaclass is **executed at the construction of the *class***, not the construction of an object. So unless you dynamically create classes, it will be called only once.

Comment: Thanks! That is perfect! I have to admit I knew **nothing** about meta-classes in python, but it seems a very powerful concept.

Comment: One question: I've tried to comment out the if ... (leaving the following line), and I expected it to work for the derived classes but not for the base one (I mean, I thought I could instantiate the derived classes but not the base class), but it does not work for both... why?

Comment: @Clonet: because the `EntityBase` is never created in that case. Since it will error on it. As a result you can not derive from that class. A dirty hack could be to add an `entityName` field to the `EntityBase` class as well, or to some checking in the `__new__` method.